# How to write a script that runs after laptop is turned on?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I got a new laptop and I'm having issues with mouse cursor. It doesn't appear when I turn on the computer, so I need to execute these two commands in terminal, and then it's ok:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Is there a way to write a script that would do this automatically after computer is turned on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would more fix the module loading than executing a script.

Edit `/etc/module` and add a line like this:

```
psmouse proto=imps
```

This will tell the kernel to load this module with the proper parameter for your mouse
 You may also work on this with a file in `/etc/modprobe.d` containing something like:

```
install psmouse /sbin/modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

But this question sounds a little off topic here...

Answer (score 2):

Add the commands to the file /etc/rc.local
(Open this file with a text editor such as nano or vim).

This file is executed whenever the linux system boots.

However, it's probably a better idea to add the modules to the file "/etc/modules".

> The  /etc/modules file contains the names of kernel modules that are
>   to
>          be loaded at boot time, one per line. Arguments can  be  given  in  the
>          same line as the module name. Lines beginning with a ’#’ are ignored.

You could try adding the module with the parameters there to see if that will work instead of having to remove and readding them using the modprobe cmd.